# Specify a vector of x and y variables for purrr::map() in conjunction with dplyr::summarise_at()

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a similar dataset but with many more `r` and `v` variables.

```
set.seed(1000)
tb <- tibble(grp = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)),
             v1 = rnorm(8),
             v2 = rnorm(8),
             v3 = rnorm(8),
             r1 = rnorm(8),
             r2 = rnorm(8))
```

For each `v` variable, I would like to create a `lm()` with `r` variables.

This is what I have so far:

lm_fun <- function(x,y) coef(lm(x ~ y))[2]

```
tb %>% 
  nest(-grp) %>%
  mutate(lm_list = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                              summarise_at(colnames(tb)[c(2:4)], funs(r1=lm_fun), .$r1)),
         lm_list2= map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                         summarise_at(colnames(tb)[c(2:4)], funs(r2=lm_fun), .$r2)),) %>%
  select(grp,lm_list,lm_list2) %>%
  unnest()
```

which gives me the intended output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  grp    v1_r1   v2_r1  v3_r1  v1_r2  v2_r2  v3_r2
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     -0.188 -0.0972  0.858  0.130 0.136   1.21 
2 B      0.208  0.935  -1.33  -0.339 0.0580 -0.840
```

However, how can I specify the `r` variables in a vector (in a similar way of specifying the `v` variables as `colnames(tb)[...]`. I don't want to copy-pasta the code for every `r` variable I have in my full data. Also, would it be possible to solve this with another method?

*Note that it is not important that the function is performing `lm()`, could be any function that involves two variables.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to loop through the 'r' columns inside `map`.  This simplifies the code as we are using the same data but different 'r' columns

```
library(tidyverse)
tb %>% 
  nest(-grp) %>%
  mutate(lm_list = map(data,  function(x)
           map(paste0('r', 1:2), function(y) 
             x %>% 
                summarise_at(vars(names(.)[1:3]), funs(lm_fun), .[[y]]) %>% 
                rename_all(~ paste(., y, sep="_")) ) %>% 
            bind_cols)) %>% 
   select(-data) %>% 
   unnest
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#  grp    v1_r1   v2_r1  v3_r1  v1_r2  v2_r2  v3_r2
#   <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A     -0.188 -0.0972  0.858  0.130 0.136   1.21 
#2 B      0.208  0.935  -1.33  -0.339 0.0580 -0.840
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to `gather` the levels of r before mutate/map:

```
tb %>% 
  gather(r, value, starts_with('r')) %>% 
  nest(-r, -grp) %>% 
  mutate(lm_list = map(
    data, ~ .x %>% 
      summarise_at(colnames(tb)[c(2:4)], funs(lm_fun), .$value)
                         )) %>% 
  unnest(lm_list, .drop = T)

  grp   r         v1      v2     v3
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     r1    -0.188 -0.0972  0.858
2 B     r1     0.208  0.935  -1.33 
3 A     r2     0.130  0.136   1.21 
4 B     r2    -0.339  0.0580 -0.840
```